# Default Slicer Selection

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

There is any way to select one default value using slicer.  Please refer to the below Screenshot.

[image]

In this image, there are multiple department names but I want to select one department and that department is my default department.
How I can select the default value?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From that multiple department names on the UI from Slicer, select your default department and save the file. That's it.

and then when ever you open the file, the selected value is the default value.
And for end users/customers, before publishing the file make sure you save the default value.

Remember the users have always able to change this value for their usage, but don't allow them save the filters.  You can make one setting on PowerBI Service, **'File -> Settings -> Don't allow end user to save Filters on this report' make this ON.** the end user won't be able to save this filter, it is you save the final selection and save and deploy. that's the final.